# Running cmd from winform

Tags: winforms, cmd

I have a question about running cmd from winform.

I have managed to connect and get information from the remote machine(infotrend disk server).

However I could not make a operation on the remote machine such "create disk part

below  I have written these code....

```
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingPath;

InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 

const string  quote = "\""; 

cmd_message = "java -jar " + quote +  "runCLI" + quote; (MANAGED TO START CLI RUN COMMAND STEP 1) 
InfotrendProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K " + cmd_message;
            
InfotrendProcess.OutputDataReceived += InfotrendProcess_OutputDataReceived1;
InfotrendProcess.ErrorDataReceived += InfotrendProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
InfotrendProcess.Start();

       using (StreamWriter sw = InfotrendProcess.StandardInput) (MANAGED TO CONNECT AND SEND DELETE 
                                                                      PART COMMAND STEP 2)
            {
              sw.WriteLine("connect " + IPNumber);
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
              sw.WriteLine("del part 01D9F2C6614DF837"); (COULD NOT SEND RESPOND y/s, MAKES NEW LINE)
              sw.WriteLine("y")
            }
```

I could not send the "y/n" respond because I have to send it in the same line after a period. Instead it makes a new line.  Should I use a different way? Could anyone help me, how I can run the final command.

Comment: Write: do not wrap after output, WriteLine: wrap after output.

Comment: Could you please, more clearly tell about "do not wrap", a few code lines might be useful 
   thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand when you mean send "y" after the time period. When the "del" action completes, should I send the "y" action? Because it's just what he's doing

Comment: It asks confirmation after a period  "You are about to delete partition. Do you want to delete y/n "  So I have to send  "y"  for yes  or "n"  for   no ....                                           I have to send the  this command in the same line.. But the code above send the confirmation in the new line.  Because  I have passed the confirmation empty, It writes "failed" and recognizes the "y" command independently  as nothing in the new line

Comment: sw.Write("del part 01D9F2C6614DF837");sw.WriteLine("y")    This will keep the two statements on one line.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to send in one line . But it takes as one line command ... here is output:......                             
RAIDCmd:> del part 01D9F2C6614DF837 y
CLI: Invalid parameter: The 'y' is invalid.
Return: 0x0005  There has to be a different way of sending separately. I put a sleep like Thread.Sleep(1000) it did not work

Comment: If you sent it in different lines like I mentioned before. The output is like this................... This Operation will result in the LOSS OF ALL DATA on the partition!
Are you sure to delete partition above ? (y or n): CLI: Failed
Return: 0x0001

RAIDCmd:> y

CLI: Unknown command: The command 'y' is unknown.
Return: 0x0006